# Android Studio and Monkeyrunner

Tags: monkeyrunner, monkey

I am using AS version 0.5.4 on a Mac. Per bash profile PATH points to

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools/
```

When I cd to that directory, I can't find monkeyrunner. I also tried updating AS but that didn't help. Has anyone used monkeyrunner with AS? Any help shall be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AS utilizes standalone Jython to run MonkeyRunner. 
Try to export your env PATH to: /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools